# Apparent violation of the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra

Tags: complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, polynomials, complex-numbers

In yesterday's introductory class on **Complex Analysis**, our professor wrote a polynomial $z^n-1=0$ and argued that this had, in principle, infinite roots given by $$z=\cos \frac{2k\pi}{n} +i \sin \frac{2k\pi}{n}$$ where $k=0,1,2,3, \ldots $.
But the number of distinct roots is $n$, obtained for $k=0,1,2, \ldots ,n-1$ after which the roots start repeating.

Although this statement of his directly violates the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra, it, unfortunately, makes sense to me. Really $\theta=0$ gives the same $z$ as $\theta=2\pi$, but the $\theta$'s are different. In that sense, he seems correct.

Where am I (and also my prof) going wrong?

Comment: Algebra is about $z$, not about $\theta$. The latter is subject of trigonometry..

Comment: When you represent a complex number $z=re^{i\theta}$, you can assume that $r\ge 0$ and $\theta \in [0,2\pi)$. Otherwise you have different representations of the same number (in this regard, every polynomial has the same issue).

Comment: The number of different $z$ is exactly $n$, the degree of the polynomial.  So this does not contradict the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra.  Just because there are different ways of writing $1$, it counts as only one zero.

Comment: The $z$'s you are considering sit on a circle in the Argand-Gauss plane, so you really have just $n$ distinct roots. I mean, if you take $z^n-1$ and split it into linear factors, you end up with $n$ linear factors, so I cannot understand your point. As far as I can see, it is not so different from saying that $1^n$ is a root of $x-1$ in $\mathbb{R}$, for every $n$.

Comment: Different representations of the same number, like $\dfrac 1 2$ and $0.5$

Comment: @EnderWiggins Well you are right about the circle.. But thats just one branch. What about the other branches?

Comment: How can you tell the difference between $1$ and $2/2$? You can't: they're both the same. How can you tell the difference between $1$ and $e^{2\pi i}$? You can't: they're both the same.

Comment: If you think this violates the theorem, it means that you think the theorem says something different from what it actually says. You need to meditate on the theorem.

Comment: @SchrodingersCat I beg your pardon, but I didn't understand. Which other branches?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=shEk8sz1oOw  ??

Comment: Suppose you are sitting on the hour hand of a clock points to the 1 and you wish to move further, say 1 hour further. Now the hour hand marks is pointing to the 2 and you are sitting on a completely new spot than the one you sat before. Move a bit more and it will point to the 3, 4, 5, ... until it points to the 1 again and you are just where you started. And even though you can keep moving, the hand hour isn't going to point to a number it hasn't pointed before. This is the case $n = 12$ and you can generalize it for arbitrary values of $n$. Hope this gives some clarification.

Comment: @GEdgar FTA does not say that number of different roots is n, rather it says the n degree polynomial has n roots in total, may or may not be different. For example, consider $(x+1)^2=0$. It has 2 roots, -1 and -1.

Comment: @SchrodingersCat ... It is better for the FTA to say the number of zeros of a degree $n$ polynomial is *at most* n.  For example, over the real numbers, $x^2+1$ has no zeros.  And, as you note, even over the complex numbers, where we expect *exactly* $n$ zeros, this depends on the technical notion of "multiplicity".  But it is still true that there are *at most* $n$ zeros.

Answer (score 4):

Let's apply similar reasoning to a simpler case: $\,x^2-1\,$ has roots $\,x = (-1)^n$ for all $n$. But even though this yields infinitely many *representations* for the roots there are only two *numbers* $\,-1,1\in \Bbb C$ that are roots, because the representations are not unique: $\,(-1)^{n} = 1\,$ for $n$ even, and $\,(-1)^{n+1} = -1\,$ for $n$ odd. Your case is analogous, except it employs higher degree roots of unity.

Answer (score 2):

For $k=0,1,2,...$ let

$z_k=\cos \frac{2k\pi}{n} +i \sin \frac{2k\pi}{n}$. Then we have

$\{z_0,z_1,z_2,...\}=\{z_0,...z_{n-1}\}$

Comment: A bit cryptic, but true.

Comment: A bit true,  but cryptic.